# prestashop Insert multiple rows in the database (batch insert)

Tags: php, prestashop

I am trying to add multiple rows to Prestashop datatable.
I have array of data to insert to Presta db,

```php
$db = Db::getInstance();
$result = $db->insert('my_table', [
      $data_arr
]);
```

and nothing. Doesn't work like that.

But when I point element of array:

```php
$db = Db::getInstance();
$result = $db->insert('my_table', [
      $data_arr[4]
]);
```

it works. Datas are being added.

acc to Presta docs:

```php
$now = date('Y-m-d H:i:s');
/** @var bool $result */
$result = $db->insert(
    'db_table',
    [
        [
            'name' => 'John Doe',
            'email' => 'john.doe@email.com',
            'date_add' => $now,
        ],
        [
            'name' => 'Jane Doe',
            'email' => 'jane.doe@email.com',
            'date_add' => $now,
        ],
    ]
);
```

And that is how my array `$data_arr` looks like:

```php
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [id] => 
            [code] => xxxzz
            [status] => 0
            [updated] => 2023-07-07 14:49:30
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [id] => 
            [code] => yyyy
            [status] => 0
            [updated] => 2023-07-07 14:19:30
        )
}
```

What am I doing wrong? Probably some stupid mistake that I can  not think of right now.

Answer (score 0):

OMG, so silly:

```php
$db = Db::getInstance();
$result = $db->insert('my_table', 
      $data_arr
);
```

I just had to remove `[]` that were near my `$data_arr`

Maybe it will be helpfull for someone.